# How to know if a user has installed, uninstalled and reinstalled a Firebase App repeatedly in a short amount of time

Tags: android, firebase

The aim of this question is:
how to know if a user has repeatedly installed, uninstalled and reinstalled a Firebase App in a short amount of time (let's say 30 minutes).
He could have done that because, for example, he had problems with the app not properly working just after the first installation.

I would like to state in advance that, in my specific case, it is not correct to use Crashlytics as my app is a TWA, that is a web app embedded into a native android app (with firebase installed). So while there are no particular problems about the native app crashes, on the other hand, the number of uninstallations is anomalous. The reason why the uninstallations is above the normal is due to some errors in the Angular web app I will fix in different ways not related to this post.

To achieve the goal I thought to observe firebase **first_open** and **app_remove** events.

Look at the attached image:
in the section **streamview** of console.firebase.google.com you can see in evidence the firebase **first_open** and **app_remove** events occurred during the last 30 minutes.

[image: Firebase first_open and app_remove events]

During this time, there have been **6** events **first_open** and **5** events **app_remove**.

#### The first question is about "first_open" event:

**first_open** event, from what I read in the documentation corresponds to an app installation event.
The **previous_first_open_count** parameter indicates the number of times the user had previously installed the app (and then uninstalled it).

The image shows that:

- **4 installations** of the app have been the first ever done by each one of the 4 users;
  that is, there have never been previous installations of the same app
  by the same user (previous_first_open_count = 0).
- **1 installation** was performed after a user had previously installed
  (and then uninstalled) the app 3 times.
- **1 installation** was finally performed after a user had previously
  installed (and then uninstalled) the app 5 more times.

Suppose that all installations, uninstallations and reinstallations shown in the image (including the **3 + 5** previous installations associated with the **previous_first_open_count** parameters) have been performed by users within the last 30 minutes.
Therefore we suppose that no previous installation has ever been performed by the six users before the last 30 minutes, but only within it.
And so the question is:
In that case, would the **first_open** events and the **previous_first_open_count** parameters have been the following?

In the last 30 minutes:

- **6 users install the app for the first time ever**
  first_open: 4 + (1 + 1) = 6 => (previous_first_open_count = 0);
- **2 of the 6 users (1 + 1) remove the app** and then install it again for the second time;
  first_open: 2 => (previous_first_open_count = 1);
- **2 users remove the app** and install it for the third time
  first_open: 2 => (previous_first_open_count = 2);
- **2 users remove the app** and install it for the fourth time
  first_open: 2 => (previous_first_open_count = 3);
- **1 user removes the app** and installs it for the fifth time
  first_open: 1 => (previous_first_open_count = 4);
- **1 user removes the app** and installs it for the sixth time
  first_open: 1 => (previous_first_open_count = 5);

... Or would the values not ​​have changed anyway, remaining those indicated in the image? That is:
In the last 30 minutes:
**4-0** (4 users install the app for the first time with 0 previous installations)
**1-3** (1 user installs the app 4 times, the last one with 3 previous installations)
**1-5** (1 user installs the app 6 times, the last one with 5 previous installations)

So, if a user in a given period of time (for example 30 minutes, 2 days or from the start of the entire period) installs, uninstalls and reinstalls the app several times, does **only its last installation is reported** in the firebase reports along with the value of the **previous_first_open_count parameter** set to the number of **total previous installations** performed by the user?
Or instead, does **each previous installation** performed by the same user during a given time matches a corresponding “**first_open**” event associated to the partial value of the previous installations (**previous_first_open_count** parameter)?
How do I figure out if the user has installed, uninstalled and reinstalled the app several times in the last 30 minutes having for example had problems with it?
Was the user forced to uninstall and reinstall the app several times in a close manner cause the app didn’t work or instead the uninstalls-reinstalls have occurred in a wider span of time?

#### The second question is about "app_remove" event:

The attached image shows that:

- 2 users uninstalled the app in the first session (**ga_session_number
  = 1**)
- 1 user uninstalled the app in the second session (**ga_session_number
  = 2**)
- 1 user uninstalled the app in the seventh session
  (**ga_session_number = 7**)
- 1 user uninstalled the app in the eighth session (**ga_session_number
  = 8**)

So if, for example, a user installs the app, starts it 8 times and then uninstalls the app on the eighth time, the **app_remove** event is associated with the **ga_session_number = 8** parameter.

But let's assume that within 30 minutes the user:

- Installs the app for the first time
- Starts the app but it does not load properly (**ga_session_number = 1**)
- Uninstalls the app
- Reinstalls the app
- Starts the newly reinstalled app for the second time but it does not
  load properly again (**ga_session_number = ?**)
- Uninstall the app
- Reinstall the app
- Start the newly reinstalled app for the third time but it does not
  load properly again (**ga_session_number = ?**)
- User repeats the above steps for 8 times within the last 30 minutes

That is, suppose that an app gets installed, uninstalled and reinstalled several times by the same user and that each time (at every installation) the app is started by the user only once due to loading problems before to be uninstalled.
Suppose that, during the first session of the eighth installation, the user uninstalls the app. In that case, is the session considered **ga_session_number = 1** or **ga_session_number = 8**?

Is there eventually another way to figure out whether an app has been installed and uninstalled several times by the same user in a short time?

Thanks.
E.F.

Answer (score 0):

I acknowledge that the question sounds a tiny bit too complex. But I think that it worth to deepen the question because, replying it could help to make definitive clarity to the fundamental concepts related to the first_open and app_remove event in Firebase.